# Grid size for package creation in Eagle

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, eaglecad, footprint, packages

I am creating a package for the first time, using Eagle for the first time.

I took measurements of the component and these are the dimensions from the center:

[image]

How exactly can I achieve these dimensions? I can use a grid spacing of 0.01 inches, but then the package will be huge.

If I use grid spacing of 0.39 inches, then the x axis will never be exact.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why will the package be huge if you use a small grid spacing?

Comment: The grid is not really important, and there is no requirement to have everything on it.  You will most likely be going into the properties of your drawing objects and manually typing in their coordinates to get them into the right places.

Comment: @SimSon Because i will have to draw until a very far away place with a Grid like this. I had some pads already, and now they look miniscule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an Eagle library package drawing, there is no requirement to have everything on grid.  The grid is just an assistant for drafting.  You can use it a lot, or a little.

My typical method is to place drawing objects (pads, silkscreen lines, text, etc) in random locations on the existing grid, and then calculate their proper coordinates and manually enter them into the Properties box.  You can manually enter coordinates and those coordinates have no relationship to the grid.

If you want to use the grid more intensively, then you would be constantly changing the grid increments and moving parts around on it.

The grid is useful for getting a sense of scale to what you are doing, and can help with error checking.  For example, it you have a set of pads at 1.27 mm pitch, you can set the grid to 1.27 mm to verify that the pads are on the right pitch.